# Three.js render not showing a simple cube when I want to show simple mesh

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I want to show a simple plane and a simple cube but the plane hides the cube, the cube is located between the camera and the plane, but the plane "hides" the cube.

This is my scene without plane:
[image]

and here it is with the plane added:
[image]

I am pretty sure they are in a location where the cube should to be showed.

Here is my code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,Window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight,0.1,1000),
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(20);
scene.add(axes);

var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(4,4,4);
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x777777});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry,cubeMaterial);
//cube.castShadow = true;
cube.position.x = 0;
cube.position.y = 10;
cube.position.z = 5;
scene.add(cube);



var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60,20);
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x55cc88});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);
plane.rotation.x = -0.5*Math.PI;
plane.position.x = 15;
plane.position.y = 0;
plane.position.z = 0;
//scene.add(plane);
//plane.receiveShadow = true;



camera.position.x = -30;
camera.position.y = 40;
camera.position.z = 30;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
spotLight.position.set(-40,60,-10);
scene.add(spotLight);


//renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE,1);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);


renderer.render(scene,camera);


$("#WebGl-salida").append(renderer.domElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to names of objects and order and correctness of parameters in methods:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,Window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight,0.1,1000)
```

should be like:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,0.1,1000)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/gavgnokb/) example

Answer (score -1):

Many thanks! Both for the answer and for the suggestion to edit the question to make it more understandable (my English has to improve) Now it is working perfectly.